# laravel many to many polymorphic relationship with custom foreign key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables

```
locationables    |locations     | account_doctor
-----------------+--------------+------------------+
**id**           |**id**        |**account_id**    |
location_id      |              |                  |
locationable_id  |              |                  |
locationable_type|              |                  |
```

would you please help me how can i write many to many polymorphic relationship between them?

I have read Laravel documentation but primary key of account_doctor table doesn't have standard conevtion cause of that relationship doesn't retrieve anything

this is my relations:

*AccountDoctor model:*

```
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(Location::class, 'locationable','locationable');
    }
```

Location model:

```
public function accountDoctors()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(AccountDoctor::class, 'locationable','locationable');
    }
```

Comment: i have read this but primary key of account_doctor is not standard and cause of that relation doesn't retrieve anything

Comment: you can change the primary key of an Eloquent model

Comment: i added     protected $primaryKey = 'account_id'; to model but still its not working

Comment: `DB::enableQueryLog()` `...dostuffhere` `dd(DB::getQueryLog())` or install laravel debugbar, or try out different parameters for the relation function

Comment: would you please right form of relationship for me tnQ

Comment: I added my relations to the question please fix mistakes of that tnQ

Comment: Read the function definition, 3rd parameter of `morphToMany` is a table name. You dont give your table name.

Comment: Let me correct that. It could be your tablename but its not in the question above.

Comment: I have edited the question please refresh the page

Comment: where's table `locationable`?

Comment: i have locationables not locationable

Comment: exactly, thats not what the function receives. I dont know if you are getting any errors from the mysql query perhaps?

Comment: I did not face any errors but result is null however I check record in locationables table

Comment: weird because I think you should pass `locationables`, since its only automatically prefilled/pluralized/deduced if you dont pass the parameter at all.

Comment: would you please write correct form of relationship for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relationship definitions should be as below

```php
class AccountDoctor extends Model
{
    public function locations()
    {
        return $this->morphToMany(
            Location::class, 
            'locationable',     //name for the morphable
            'locationables',    //pivot table
            'locationable_id',  //foreign key on the pivot table to identify this model record
            'location_id',      //foreign key on the pivot table to identify related model record
            'account_id',       //primary key column name for this model's table
            'id'                //primary key column name for related model's table
        );
    }
}
```

And

```php
class Location extends Model
{
    public function account_doctors()
    {
        return $this->morphedByMany(
            AccountDoctor::class, 
            'locationable',     //name for the morphable 
            'locationables',    //pivot table 
            'location_id',      //foreign key on the pivot table to identify this model record 
            'locationable_id',  //foreign key on the pivot table to identify related model record 
            'id',               //primary key column name for this model's table
            'account_id'        //primary key column name for related model's 
        );
    }
}
```